# DD-WRT Universal Repeater [Atheros Chipset]

Tags: networking, dd-wrt, wireless-bridge, repeater, bridging

How can I Setup DD-WRT Router to be Universal Repeater?

Premise

- Wireless 3G/4G Modem (Netgear AC762s, as example although irrelevant) as Internet connection
- Home Router (Any DD-WRT capable Router, Atheros chipset in this case) for network devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had luck this this Firmware: DD-WRT v24-sp2 (06/23/14) std, the previous one to it did not work. Router is a Netgear WNR2200

Factory Reset DD-WRT Router before you bbegin to be sure;
30sec pin, Power off hold, hold pin, Power on for 30 seconds, unplug, power back on. Confirm factory settings, you should be asked to choose a username and password when you next connect to the Webadmin of the Router

### Modem Settings [192.168.**1**.1]

- Set Wifi Channel to a static one [eg. Channel 2].
- Wifi Security =  WPA2 Personal - AES

### Router Settings [save changes on each page before moving on]

#### Setup Page

#### WAN Connection Type

- Automatic Configuration - DHCP [Once you get it working you can be more specific, ie, set to static]

#### Basic

- Configure Lan settings, Use a different Network Range [192.168.**2**.1] to the Wireless Modem.
- Gateway = Modem IP Address
- Local DNS = Router IP Address

#### Advanced Routing

- Set to "gateway".

#### DHCP

- Static DNS 1 = Router IP Address
- Static DNS 2 = 8.8.8.8 [optional]

#### Wireless

- Match Modem Wifi Settings, set to Client Mode
- Add a second Wifi as Access Point Mode, name whatever you like, again match Modem Security settings, WPA2-AES.

Apply Settings, reboot.
You should now have a WAN IP top Right.

If not Check Wireless settings, put in fake password, apply, put back correct password, apply.